# Why strtok takes a char* and not a const char*?

Tags: c++

As far as I can understand `strtok()` doesn't modify the underlying string, so why doesn't it not take a const `char*` pointer rather than a `const char*` pointer? Also while tokenizing you wouldn't want your string to change, right?

Updated: 
https://godbolt.org/z/3SPvRB
It is clear that strtok() does modify the underlying string. What is the alternative for an non-mutating tokenizer?

Comment: "`strtok()` doesn't modify the underlying string" - says what documentation? It absolutely modifies the underlying string. As it identifies points od delimitation is drops nullchars to replace those delimiters and deliver your tokens. See [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: But why should it if it is tokenizing? I can understand there is an another function called `strcspn` for those cases, but why?

Comment: To prove it to yourself, try `strtok ("hello world", " \n");` and see what results... And the *"Why should it?"* part is simply the wrong question. It does, that's the way it was written. That's also one of the caveats or criticisms of `strtok()`. Yes a combination of `strspn` and `strcspn` will let you tokenize without modifying the underlying string. (or just manually walk a pair of pointers down the string bracketing tokens and using `memcpy` will do as well)

Comment: How else would `strtok` work?  The pointer it returns is a pointer into the original string you passed to it.  The only way for other string routines to recognize the end of the token is for it to drop nul characters into the original string on token boundries.

Comment: Yes, it does (https://godbolt.org/z/DXmfZ8). Is there a non mutating way to do the same?

Comment: [What to do when your question is based on a factually incorrect premise?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340223/what-to-do-when-your-question-is-based-on-a-factually-incorrect-premise)

Comment: @PradeepKumar sure, you may be overthinking this one too. Just make a copy of the original string and tokenize the copy. The other alternatives I mention work well. For C++11, you can also use `.find_first_not_of()` and `.find_first_of()` along with `.substr()` to walk down the string spanning tokens in a way that doesn't modify the original. There are many examples on the site already.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the comment. I will try it out

Comment: Note that C++ provides alternatives (imo, superior alternatives) to C `strtok` for string tokenization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated: https://godbolt.org/z/3SPvRB It is clear that `strtok()` does
>   modify the underlying string. What is the alternative for an
>   non-mutating tokenizer?

As mentioned in the comments, you can either:

1. make a copy of the original string and then tokenize the copy with `strtok()`; or
2. write your own implementation that brackets the tokens and copies the tokens to new storage:

   - using C `strspn` to scan forward to the first non-delimiter character which will be the beginning of the token, then use `strcspn` to scan forward to the next delimiter marking the end of the token,
   - do the same thing manually with a pair of pointers; or
   - for C++11 or later, you can use `.find_first_not_of()` to scan forward to the first non-delimiter character, and then `.find_first_of()` to locate the delimiter that follows the token.

In each case you will then copy the token characters to a new string (using `memcpy` for C-type implementation -- don't forget to *nul-terminate*) or for C++11 simply using the `.substr()` member function.

A very-basic C++11 implementation would look similar to:

```
std::vector<std::string> stringtok (const std::string& s, const std::string& delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v {};  /* vector of strings for tokens */
    size_t beg = 0, end = 0;        /* begin and end positons in str */

    /* while non-delimiter char found */
    while ((beg = s.find_first_not_of (delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = s.find_first_of (delim, beg);       /* find delim after non-delim */
        v.push_back (s.substr (beg, end - beg));  /* add substr to vector */
        if (end == std::string::npos)             /* if last delim, break */
            break;
    }

    return v;   /* return vector of tokens */
}
```

If you follow the logic, it tracks exactly what is described above the function definition. Combining it into a short example, you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> stringtok (const std::string& s, const std::string& delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v {};  /* vector of strings for tokens */
    size_t beg = 0, end = 0;        /* begin and end positons in str */

    /* while non-delimiter char found */
    while ((beg = s.find_first_not_of (delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = s.find_first_of (delim, beg);       /* find delim after non-delim */
        v.push_back (s.substr (beg, end - beg));  /* add substr to vector */
        if (end == std::string::npos)             /* if last delim, break */
            break;
    }

    return v;   /* return vector of tokens */
}

int main (void) {

    std::string str = "    my           dog   has    fleas      ",
                delim = " ";
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    tokens = stringtok (str, delim);

    std::cout << "string: '" << str << "'\ntokens:\n";
    for (auto s : tokens)
        std::cout << "  " << s << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stringtok
string: '    my           dog   has    fleas      '
tokens:
  my
  dog
  has
  fleas
```

Note: this is only one of many ways to implement a string tokenization that does not modify the original. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 7):

But `strtok` **DOES** change the string.

Take the following code:

```
char sz[] = "The quick brown fox";
char* token = strtok(sz, " ");
```

It's going to alter the contents of the array into:

```
"The\0quick brown fox";
```

The first discovered delimiter gets replaced with a null char.  Internally (via thread local storage or global variable), the pointer to the the next char past the discovered delimiter is stored such that a subsequent call to `strtok(NULL, " ")` will parse the next token from the original string.

Comment: "*That's what enables `strtok(NULL, "")` to know how to advance to the next token from the original parse*" - not true. It knows where to continue parsing from because it internally keeps track of where it left off. The sole purpose of injecting nulls into the source string is to allow the caller to treat each returned token as a separate null-terminated string.

Comment: It takes multiple calls to `strtok` to do this. Just one call only transforms the first space. This allows you to use different delimiters for each call.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It does modify the underlying string. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

> This *end of the token* is automatically replaced by a null-character, and the *beginning
>   of the token* is returned by the function.

Proof:

```cpp
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }

  /* note this line... */
  printf ("str = \"%s\"\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```cpp
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
a
sample
string
str = "- This"
```